# Pygame window freezing with shell input

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4

So, I have a game that is controlled by shell input. The problem I'm having is that whenever I click on the Pygame window, it stops responding. It starts responding as soon as I enter more shell input, but it's still something that I would rather not have occurring. The way the game works, so that you can try it, is you just enter `x += (a number)` or `y += (a number)`, and it will  change your player's position. Any ideas on how to prevent the freezing up? I tried using threading instead of putting the input in the `while` loop, but then I couldn't modify the variables in the function.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 1366
display_height = 768

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A game for teaching python')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
crashed = False
carImg = pygame.image.load('player.png')
def player(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))
x =  (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)
x_change = 0
car_speed = 0
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True     
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    player(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
    exec(input(">>> "))

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: see: [Pygame: Graphical Input + Text Input](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13451666/4594443)

Answer (score 1):

I've made a game extremely similar to this. What I did is created a Player() class, and then used threads to make a console so I could edit the Player.x and Player.y attributes. For example:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self,startx,starty):
        self.x = startx
        self.y = starty

    #Move method is optional, as you can just edit the x and y attributes
    #directly
    def move(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x += x
        self.y += y
```

Now, to make a good threaded console you'd do the following.

```
import thread
consoling = False

def threadedConsole():
    global consoling
    consoling = True
    try:
        exec(raw_input(">> "))
    except Exception as error:
        print error
    consoling = False

#Game loop
while True:
    if not consoling: thread.start_new_thread(threadedConsole,())
    #Game stuff
```

Then you just call Player.move method in the console. Global variables aren't editable in a thread, but objects are. Sorry for the messy code by the way, I'm only 15.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way that come to my mind:
The first one is using threads: one for the shell and one other for pygame program.
The second one is to get your inputs from the window instead of using the shell.
Let imagine you initialise a variable named "number" at 0, you can adapt this code to yours:

```
    elif i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if i.unicode in [str (i) for i in range(10)]:
            number = number * 10 + int (i.unicode)
```